# Unexpected behavior with the CSS 'ch' unit

Tags: javascript, css, electron, character, width

I am using the `ch` CSS unit for specifying the width of a `div` containing text. I am using a monospaced font. However, if I set  `width: 80ch`, I get 80 characters for the first `n` lines (where `n` is always 24, not sure if this matters!), but then only 79 characters from then onwards. This is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: The point where it goes from 80 characters per line to 79, when width: 80ch.]

It seems like this could be some rounding issue. If I set the `width: 80.01ch`, I always get 80 characters, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: With width: 80.01ch, there are always 80 chars per line.]

Is this a known issue? I guess I've found a workaround by setting it to `80.1ch` (or even `80.01ch`, that works too), but it's definitely not what I would expect.

Here is a minimal snippet which illustrates the issue. Scroll down to see the 80 chars per line drop to 79 chars.][3]

```html
<div id="rx-data" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; font-family: monospace; overflow-y: scroll;"><div style="width: 80ch;"><span style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-all;">0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789</span></div></div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: works perfecty for me https://jsfiddle.net/6a54e3hu/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've added a link to a minimal JSFiddle highlighting the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder woops sorry about that, I have hopefully now updated it correctly to contain a Stackoverflow snippet.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder interesting. It demonstrates the problem for me both in Chrome and Edge on Windows 10 here for me. I've uploaded a screenshot to https://imgur.com/a/craQgus

Comment: @gbmhunter - **It replicates for me too on Windows** using Chrome v87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit). But not on Linux using that exact same build [Chrome v87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)]. Also Edge Version 87.0.664.66 (Official build) (64-bit) (which is Chromium-based). But not Firefox v84.0.1 (different layout engine). Weird!

Comment: I've verified there are no unusual characters hidden in there, etc. Probably worth reporting [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks for the patience and advice @T.J.Crowder, I have created a bug report at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1162838

Do you think it's worth opening this post up to the public? I think it contains some useful findings they may help someone in the future if they stumble across the same problem.

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't reproduce at all on a Mac (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari). But it happened after only 6 lines on Windows w/ Chrome.

Comment: @gbmhunter - I'm not sure what you mean by "...opening this post up to the public..." Closed questions are viewable to everyone, so everyone can benefit from the information in the question. I don't see much reason to reopen the question to *answers* if that's what you mean, since it's fairly clear that it's a bug that will presumably get fixed at some point now it's been reported.

Comment: Duoh! @T.J.Crowder sorry I didn't realize exactly what "closed" inferred. I thought I remembered reading something along the lines of "This post is only visible to you and needs more work", I didn't realize it was now public (and might have always been). Apologies on my behalf.

Comment: @gbmhunter - No worries! :-) (You're probably remembering having read something on a *deleted* question. This question is just closed, not deleted.)

Comment: Yeah the "closed question" explanation notice might itself be confusing. If I understand correctly, it is the explanation itself that is "viewable only to [some people]", but the question (and the closed notice) is still public. There is https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions, but still not saying explicitly that the question is still visible to everyone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566144/using-css-js-to-force-div-to-width-of-x-chars/66569026 seems relevant

Comment: Works properly for me in Chrome 107 for Mac.