# Using css/js to force div to width of X chars?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a page that recieves a large string, 500*500 characters (initially all spaces, `' '`). I then render this with a monospace font into a `<div>`, with width and height set to 500ch.

```js
let text = "";
let char = ' ';
for (var i = 0; i < 500 * 500; i++) {
  if (!(i % 500)) {
    char = '|'
  }
  text += char;
  char = ' ';
}

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
```

```css
:root {
  --pwidth: 500ch;
}

body {
  background-color: #111111;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 14;
  margin: none;
  width: var(--pwidth);
  color: #EEEEEE;
  resize: none;
  display: block;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

The result is odd. The string index of every line should be an even number: 0, 500, 1000 (...)
However the rendered result is something like this:

```
|0
|500
|1000
|1500
|2000
|2500
 |3000
  |3500
   |4000
    |4500
```

This doesn't happen in Firefox, but on Chrome and Edge it does. It is as if the browsers decide to break the line prematurely. Is there any way to achieve the desired effect on atleast the popular browsers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). I've done the first bit for you by putting what you had in the question into the Stack Snippet, but the missing bit -- the HTML -- is important.

Comment: Is there any other CSS setting at all (other than what browsers put in)? And, is there a reason for defining the height?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the html.

Comment: @AHaworth no, there are no other CSS settings. most of the app is javascript not related to . I removed the height setting in both css and js, but I still get the same result.

Comment: @sydnytt - I'm afraid you've misunderstood the point of Stack Snippets. They're for **runnable** examples. You put the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript all together in a single snippet (you'll note the original I did for you had the JavaScript and CSS in it). Please see [that link I gave you earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) and update your question with a **runnable** example of the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. Im afraid it's not possible to run the code on here, since it communicates with a socket.io and node backend to populate the div, why I initially used the ```. I do have the full app on [https://github.com/sydnytt/text-space](https://github.com/sydnytt/text-space).

Comment: @sydnytt - Please read the [MRE link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I gave you above. There's no reason that your example has to talk to socket.io. You've asked an HTML / CSS question. You can put whatever data you need for it in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I finally understood the snippet function. I will attempt to reproduce the problem, which does not occur when i run the code here.

Comment: @sydnytt - I've seen something like this here, just a few weeks ago -- Blink suddenly deciding after a bunch of lines to make their length different. Can't find it how (helpful!). :-) FWIW, though, I wouldn't rely on wordwrap for this, I'd break up the output into 500 divs with 500 chars each.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess you are right about breaking it up into 500 divs. I plan on doing that as updating innerhtml with 250000 chars at typing speed seems to lag in most browsers (except firefox!). Thanks for all the info!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am assuming you are talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526443/unexpected-behavior-with-the-css-ch-unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not occur when run as a SO snippet apparently.

My suspicion therefore is that the code as run elsewhere does not correctly set up a Doctype. SO snippets tend to have such 'missing bits' added automatically.

I have run the following code on Chrome/Edge/Firefox on Windows 10 and all give a 'vertical straight line' of As down the left hand side, ie the expected result.

However, if I remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` Chrome and Edge layout mainly diagonally, with the odd 'blip' of two As vertically above each other. I suspect in those cases you are getting some additive rounding errors, but I can't prove it.

In the StackOverflow environment, a doctype will be added so you don't see the problem.

Here's the code that runs OK outside the SO environment. Note the original given code has several errors ('none' is not OK value for padding or margin for example) but these did  not affect the final result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  :root {
      --pwidth: 500ch;
      --pheight: 500ch;
    }

   body {
      background-color: #111111;
      top: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Courier, monospace;
      font-size: 14;
      margin: 0;
      width: var(--pwidth);
      height: var(--pheight);
      height: auto;
      resize: none;
      display: block;
      white-space: break-spaces;
      overflow-wrap: anywhere;
      border: none;
    }
    #text {
      background: pink;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="text"></div>
<script>

const textEl = document.querySelector('#text');
let str = '';
for (let i = 0; i< 500; i++) { str += 'A'; for (j = 0; j<499 ; j++) {str +=' '; }}
textEl.innerHTML = str;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. It's helpful, but better posted as a comment with a link or even an edit (since links off-site are not good).

Comment: Hi, not sure how I'd get all that into a comment -what should I have done?

Comment: As I said above: *"...but better posted as a comment with a link or even an edit (since links off-site are not good)"*

Comment: Ah, I didn't put up a link because people tend to get their knuckles wrapped for that. I wasn't confident about editing the question - what would it have shown, something that was working so not a question any more? Also editing someone else's work is quite problematic - how not to upset them? In this case also putting in a 'proper' snippet made the problem go away. Think I'll stick to putting such stuff in an answer, especially since (I suspect, as said) that absence of doctype is probably the problem. It would be nice to be able to have code in a comment, but realise that's not possible.

Comment: It's frankly a really awkward situation, fortunately it doesn't come up that much. **Please** don't post non-answer answers. FWIW, I usually post a comment with a link to something like pastbin or jsFiddle. Comments are ephemeral and the purpose of the comment (and link) is to elicit feedback from the OP so them being fleeting and the content being off-site isn't that bad (whereas hiding your question or answer off site is very much not okay). I've never had my knuckles rapped for that. (Now, I'm a very high-rep user, but there are lots of folks who rap my knucklse over other things... :-D)

Comment: @AHaworth I was not at all aware of the significance of <!DOCTYPE html>. I asked the wrong question (css/js). This definitely achieved my desired result and I will mark this as solved. Thank you. Now to optimize the whole thing for speed...

Comment: Glad it worked. Doctype is a bit of a hidden thing isn’t it.